# SwiftUI: What is the Proper Logic Statement to Prevent Views From Disappearing While Using a Custom Slider

Tags: swiftui

My SwiftUI Views are disappearing when I am using a custom made slider. I believe it is because the frame values of the Views are becoming negative; however, I feel that I have coded the logic correctly to prevent this from happening (but something is wrong).

I have tried several different if statements to prevent the values from becoming negative but am having no luck.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
@State private var dragged = CGSize.zero
@State private var accumulated = CGSize.zero

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .stroke()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 5, alignment: .leading)
            .position(x: 180, y: 30)
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 0 + dragged.width, height: 5, alignment: .leading)
            .position(x: 30 + (0.5 * dragged.width), y: 30)
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20).border(Color.red)
            .position(x: 30, y: 30)
            .offset(x: self.dragged.width)
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged{ value in

//My IF-Statement
                    if value.translation.width > 0 {
                        self.dragged = CGSize(
                            width: value.translation.width + self.accumulated.width,
                            height: value.translation.height + self.accumulated.height
                        )
                    }
            }
            .onEnded{ value in
                self.dragged = CGSize(
                    width: value.translation.width + self.accumulated.width,
                    height: value.translation.height + self.accumulated.height)
                self.accumulated = self.dragged
                }
        )
        VStack{
            Text("\(dragged.width)")
            Text("\(30 + (0.5 * dragged.width))")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The error occurs when I slide the red circle too far to the left very quickly. I am expecting the IF statement to stop the circle before it makes the variable negative (if my assumption is correct about what is making it disappear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Limit to the right

You don't need an if statement, but rather a maximum the *width* can go. One way to do it to use `min(maxValue, calculated)` to enforce the *width* to not go beyond `maxValue`.

### Limit to the left

Your drag starts at the red dot, but dragging is not limited to your drawn scale, but you can rather drag to the left of it since the screen continues until the screen edge, which makes drags to the left go negative.

To avoid it you can check whether the result is negative and if so, just use 0 instead of the negative value, like below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SliderView: View {

    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State private var dragged = CGSize.zero
    @State private var accumulated = CGSize.zero

    let maxWidth: CGFloat = 300

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .stroke()
                .frame(width: maxWidth, height: 5, alignment: .leading)
                .position(x: 180, y: 30)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 0 + dragged.width, height: 5, alignment: .leading)
                .position(x: 30 + (0.5 * dragged.width), y: 30)
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20).border(Color.red)
                .position(x: 30, y: 30)
                .offset(x: self.dragged.width)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged{ value in
                        print("on changed called. width: \(value.translation.width)")

                        self.dragged = CGSize(
                            width: value.translation.width + self.accumulated.width > 0 ?
                                min(self.maxWidth, value.translation.width + self.accumulated.width) : 0,
                            height: value.translation.height + self.accumulated.height
                        )
                }
                .onEnded{ value in
                    self.dragged = CGSize(
                        width: value.translation.width + self.accumulated.width > 0 ?
                            min(self.maxWidth, value.translation.width + self.accumulated.width) : 0,
                        height: value.translation.height + self.accumulated.height)
                    self.accumulated = self.dragged
                    }
            )
            VStack{
                Text("\(dragged.width)")
                Text("\(30 + (0.5 * dragged.width))")
            }
        }
    }
}
```